# How does a circularBuffer improve performance vs competing for a particular memory address(mutex suspends the other)?

Tags: c++, memory-management, architecture, circular-buffer

In theory memory circularBuffer sounds like a good idea... the setting and the getting are never at the same address.  However the limiting factor in the hardware.  The computer will only allow use to access one memory location at a time.  So then how can a circularBuffer improve performance ??

Comment: Actually, it's no longer true that the computer only allows one memory access at once - a lot of hardware has support for simultaneous read/write access (i.e., one read and one write can be made at the same time). Also, over what do you think the circular buffer improves performance?

Comment: 'improve performance' over what?

Comment: I'm using circular buffers that overwrite older entries with new entries because of limited memory.  The only performance oprimization I know of is to use a power of 2 for the capacity so that modulo and division operations are not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/single-writer-principle.html) gives some reasons why circular buffers offer better performance than synchronized access to a single, shared data structure.

What hardware are you using, that only allows access to one memory location at a time?